# Drag and drop an image not contained in a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, drawing

I have a problem with my code. I want to make a method to drag and drop an small image contained on a drawing panel, but this is only an image, is not contained in a pictureBox control.

```
private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g.DrawPath(pluma, gP);

        if(nuevobloque)
        {
            g.DrawImage(bloque, new Point(200, 200));
            nuevobloque = false;
        }
    }
```

There I draw the image on the panel, but I don't know how I can drag and drop that image. Once again, is not contained on a pictureBox control.

Also, I want to know how can I keep the images in place even if I scroll over the panel (I don't want them to dissapear when I scroll the panel).

Thank you.

Comment: Which part is the problem: doing drag&drop or having the data ready? For the former I recommend using mouseup/down/move, which i find easier for in-programm d&d. For the latter you have a choice of either keeping the bitmap chached, maybe in the panel's Tag or copying it from the Panel's surface using control.DrawToBitmap. Hard to tell which is better, the former seems more natural, but don't forget disposing of it when you're done with it; the latter will only create what is actually needed..

Comment: As for keeping the image from being scrolled, I don't think that is possible. It will be easier to move another Panel or a PictureBox over your Panel. Make sure it doesn't become a Child of the Panel! For this you can __move it in place with the keyboard instead of the mouse!__ sounds weird but it will work.. Instead of drawing it you can use the BackgroundImage property of the 2nd Panel, which will also solve the question of where to keep it!